# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException when trying to run JavaFX application in visual studio code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, javafx

I am attempting to run a JavaFX application in visual studio code, and whenever I run it, I get the following stack trace. I am not sure how to set my resources folder as the resource root in VS code, so I put "resources/view/MainScene.fxml" as the file path for the FXMLLoader. I also tried using the full file path from the C drive, but same result. I have also checked that the FXML file has the proper controller selected (main.java.controller.AppController) and I have included the following in the launch.json file:

```
"vmArgs": "--module-path \"C:/Java/javafx-sdk-19/lib\" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
        at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
        at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
        at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3324)
        at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3287)
        at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3255)
        at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3227)
        at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3203)
        at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3196)
        at main.java.application.App.start(App.java:20)
        at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
        at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
        at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
        at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
        at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
        ... 1 more
Exception running application main.java.application.App
```

Here is my folder structure:

```
|-src
    |-main
        |-java
            |-application
                |-App.java ---location of main method being run
            |-controllers
                |-AppController.java
            |-services
                |-HttpConection.java
        |-resources
            |-view
                |-MainScene.fxml
```

Here is my FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<AnchorPane fx:id="mainPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="main.java.controllers.AppController">
   <children>
      <GridPane fx:id="displayGrid" layoutX="11.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="372.0" prefWidth="578.0">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Here is my App.java file where I am trying to run the application:

```
package main.java.application;


import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        
        try {
            AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("resources/view/MainScene.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);

            primaryStage.setTitle("Application");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
}
```

Here is the launch.json file:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Launch Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "${file}"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Launch App",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "main.java.application.App",
            "projectName": "FrontEnd_2e0d9572",
            "vmArgs": "--module-path \"C:/Java/javafx-sdk-19/lib\" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the settings.json file:

```
{
    "java.project.sourcePaths": ["src"],
    "java.project.outputPath": "bin",
    "java.project.referencedLibraries": [
        "lib/**/*.jar"
    ]
}
```

I'm pretty certain it's something to do with the FXML file, but I am not sure what exactly. I can update the post with any additional details that are needed.

Comment: If you're using Maven's/Gradle's standard directory layout (i.e., `src/main/java` and `src/main/resources`), then `resources` should never be part of the resource path (the argument to `getResource(...)`).

Comment: @Slaw Note, however, the package name for `App`. In this (highly non-standard) setup, the “correct” path is perhaps `”/main/resources/view/MainScene.fxml”`. It’s probably better to fix the setup though.